# Azure VMSS : Retrieve FQDN

Tags: azure

I have created a Virtual machine scale set in Azure and now require to access FQDN of instance from inside of VM. Tried these:
1. Using Azure metadata service. It surprisingly does not have FQDN field.
2. used Hostname -f it gave an fqdn but I think it is to be used internally in azure as it is not accessible from outside.
3. Tried listing public IP of VMSS but how to filter it to show public ip related my VM escapes me.

Update : In AWS "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname" commands give the intended output. I am looking for its equivalent

Comment: Are you try to access one VM of the VMSS from outside? RDP or WEB?

Comment: my application requires it as input. and yes I should be able to connect it from outside.

Comment: Are you want to get VM's outgoing IP address?

Comment: Please try this command `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'` to get it.

Comment: no the DNS name which is set along with network setting of VMSS. Ip address i can get from metadata service.

Comment: Domainnamelabel parameter in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it's **not** possible to get FQDN from metadata server.

More information about data categories are available through the Instance Metadata Service, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service#instance-metadata-data-categories).

Does your VMSS instances create with public IP addresses? if yes, you can use Powershell or Azure portal to find the FQDN.

Comment: Humm !! I knew about metadata service as I explained in my question. but still need to find the FQDN

Comment: Could you use PowerShell or Azure CLI to get it?

Comment: my problem is I need FQDN for each instance and there is no command which gives FQDN according to some unique property of VM.If you know please let me know

Comment: @BlindSniper As a workaround, maybe you can use use powershell or CLI, and login your azure account, use this command `(Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name jasonlb -ResourceGroupName jasonvm).DnsSettings.Fqdn`.

Comment: Hi Jason thanx for the command. I got that using the command and jmes querypath. but that is not a very clean solution. Microsoft does want their developers to work harders :((